# Problems with gtk2 programming

Tags: programming, gtk

I'm starting to learn C and GTK2. So, I find tutorial at [zetcode.com](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/), and try to make a little program, but it doesn't want to start. I'm doing exactly as in tutorial, but there's some bug in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int count = 0;
char buf[5];

void increase(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label)
{
 count++;

 sprintf(buf, "%d", count);
 gtk_label_set_text(label, buf);
}

void decrease(GtkWidget *window, gpointer label)
{
 count--;

 sprintf(buf, "%d", count);
 gtk_label_set_text(label, buf);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 GtkWidget *label;
     GtkWidget *window;
 GtkWindow *frame;
 GtkWindow *plus;
 GtkWindow *minus;

 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
 gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 100);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Math");

 frame = gtk_fixed_new();
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

 plus = gtk_button_new_with_label("+");
 gtk_widget_set_size_request(plus, 80, 35);
 gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), plus, 50, 20);

 minus = gtk_button_new_label("-");
 gtk_widget_set_size_request(minus, 80, 35);
 gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), minus, 50, 20);

 label = gtk_label_new("0");
 gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), label, 190, 58);

 gtk_widget_show_all(window);

 g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
 g_signal_connect(plus, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(increase), label);
 g_signal_connect(minus, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(decrease), label);

 gtk_main();

 return 0;
}
```

Pls, help.

Comment: This should be on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). You could also ask on the 'Programming Talk' section of the [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=39).

Comment: What is the build command you use to compile this source? What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 4):

This line is wrong:

```
minus = gtk_button_new_label("-");
```

It should be:

```
minus = gtk_button_new_with_label("-");
```